# meteor: design pattern : create template helper for each field (column) of collection

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, meteor

Using meteor js,
I notice that if i have documents like this

`{"q1":"someValue1","q2":"someValue2","q3":"someValue3","q4":"someValue4"}`

quite often my helpers end up like this
EDIT: I end up repeating the creation of helper-per-field a lot

```
Template.whatever.helpers({
gimmeResults1: function(){return myCollection.find({},{fields:{"q1":1}})},

gimmeResults2: function(){return myCollection.find({},{fields:{"q2":1}})}
});
```

with averaging one field in a really ugly way such as

```
q1Avg: function () {
  var count = myCollection.find({},{fields:{"q1":1}}).count();
  var total = 0;
  myCollection.find({},{fields:{"q1":1}}).map(function(doc) {
    total += doc.q1;
  });
  return avg = (Math.round((total / count)*100))/100;
}
```

(using a variable would still entail multiple db queries, correct?)

is there some design pattern I should be using to iterate over fields of a document and-autocreate template helpers?

what other ways can I eliminate spaghetti code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's the reason to limit the fetched fields in a helper?

Comment: Hi Hubert, I've edited my post above to be more clear. thanks for your time on this- i'm quite often creating helper-per-field functions and this seems repetitive and probably noob and wrong...is there a design pattern that people usually use to create helpers based on single field queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step might look like this:

```
getField = function(collection, field) {
  var projection = {};
  projection[field] = 1;
  return collection.find({}, {fields: projection});
}
UI.registerHelper("getField", getField);
```

Which you would call in your templates like `{{getField myCollection "q1"}}`, together with a helper returning `myCollection`. You could take it further:

```
var makeFieldGetter = function(collection, field) {
  return function() {
    return getField(collection, field);
  };
};

Template.whatever.helpers({
  gimmeResults1: makeFieldGetter(myCollection, "q1")
  gimmeResults2: makeFieldGetter(myCollection, "q2")
});
```

Or even further:

```
var makeFieldGetters = function(collection, fields) {
  var obj = {};
  fields.forEach(function(field) {
    obj["gimme_" + field] = makeFieldGetter(collection, field);
  });
  return obj;
};

Template.whatever.helpers(makeFieldGetters(myCollection, ["q1", "q2"]));
// creates helpers gimme_q1, gimme_q2
```

Comment: wow! thanks. so, would I be right in saying that in all 3 examples it's essentially about having a variable projection, and then making sure it's registered as a helper?  is there a name for this pattern you are showing me? I really appreciate the time you took to break this out